# SQL Server - Msg 4104 on Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-update

I'm working on SQL Server 2008. I'm trying to update records based upon a value in another table. I keep getting an error saying that the multipart identifier at line 5 and 6 can't be bound. Based upon what I have read it seem that this is an aliasing problem so I did not use any aliases, but I am still stuck. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_procedure]
SET [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_procedure].location_id=[REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_encounter].location_id
FROM [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_encounter]
JOIN [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_procedure] 
ON [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_procedure].enc_id=[REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_encounter].enc_id
WHERE [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_procedure].enc_id='5EFE0E0B-447E-4D64-ADAB-001D084914A5'
```

Comment: Of course you've already checked for the data type ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
  UPDATE [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_procedure] a
SET a.location_id=b.location_id
FROM [REPORTING].[Prod].[dbo].[patient_encounter] b
inner JOIN a
ON a.enc_id=b.enc_id
WHERE a.enc_id='5EFE0E0B-447E-4D64-ADAB-001D084914A5'
```

or just try this one:::

```
UPDATE table1 a
SET a.location_id=b.location_id
FROM table b
inner JOIN a
ON a.enc_id=b.enc_id
WHERE a.enc_id='5EFE0E0B-447E-4D64-ADAB-001D084914A5'
```

Note: Table one is the table to be updated while table 2 is the table which is to be joined.
Thnnk you